# How to calculate the actual number for each day using start and end date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to calculate the number of distinct ID for each date. Is there a way to do it only with SQL, without using PL/SQL?

```
create table test (
    id number(10),
    start_date timestamp,
    end_date timestamp
);

insert into test values(1, to_date('01.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  to_date('03.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into test values(2, to_date('02.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  to_date('05.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
insert into test values(3, to_date('04.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  to_date('06.01.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy'));
```

I need a `SELECT` statement to get something like this:

```
01.01.2019 1
02.01.2019 2
03.01.2019 2
04.01.2019 2
05.01.2019 2
06.01.2019 1
```

Comment: dates can be done unique but is there any logic behind the numbers displayed as a result in second column.

Comment: The second column shows how many IDs are actual for the date. The ID is actual for the date if the date is between start_date and end_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point to solve this is to generate a list of dates for which you want the number of distinct id to be counted. THen you can simply `JOIN` this list with the table and turn on aggregation.

Here is a simple solution that builds the list of date from the distinct values available in both columns containing dates in the original table. Other (better) options exists, using a recursive subquery or a calendar table.

```
SELECT dt.mydate, COUNT(DISTINCT id_number) cnt
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT start_date mydate FROM test 
        UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT end_date  FROM test 
    ) dt
    LEFT JOIN test t ON dt.mydate >= t.start_date AND dt.mydate <= t.end_date
GROUP BY dt.mydate
ORDER BY dt.mydate
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c3f420d53367e893d54be44525f8bc6c)** with your sample data returns:

```
MYDATE                       | CNT
:--------------------------- | --:
01-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000 AM |   1
02-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000 AM |   2
03-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000 AM |   2
04-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000 AM |   2
05-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000 AM |   2
06-JAN-19 12.00.00.000000 AM |   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can try to use cte recursive

```
WITH   CTE(id,start_date,end_date) AS
(
        SELECT  id,start_date ,end_date
        FROM test
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id,start_date ,cast((end_date - 1) as date)
        FROM CTE 
        WHERE start_date <= cast((end_date - 1) as date)
)
SELECT  end_date,COUNT(*)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY end_date
ORDER BY end_date
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/RJNX81111)

Or using `CONNECT BY`

```
SELECT dt,count(*)
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT end_date,start_date + LEVEL dt
    FROM    test
    CONNECT BY extract(day from end_date - start_date) - LEVEL + 1 >= 0
) t1
GROUP BY dt
ORDER BY dt
```

[sqlfiddle](https://rextester.com/EZXS52288)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT start_date,COUNT(Id_number) from test group by start_date
```

This way allows you group your rows by date (start date or end date, whatever you prefer), and count the rows with the same date.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I also need dates in between start_date and end_date. So it is not a solution.